# Strange crash opening Firefox (only on work machine)

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I've got a little test suite working on my laptop which I've tried to transfer over to my work desktop.  To, hopefully, make things easier, I used the same version of Java and maven.  However, typically, it's not been so easy :)

When I started Firefox, I got a "Firefox has stopped working" message box.  The message box indicated the issue lay with "xul.dll" - so I closed the box and Firefox opened.  It does this everytime I open Firefox.

I have even stripped out all my allure and other code and just ran a simple case:

`WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();`
`driver.get("http://www.google.co.uk");`

However this doesn't work either.

It was then I checked the versions of Firefox were the same, turns out they weren't - but the Firefox updated fixed that.  But my test still passes on the laptop, but fails on the desktop.  I can't see anything I have missed, I can see one possible issue - the work desktop has Kaspersky installed.

Has anyone ever experienced what I've described?

Comment: Do you deploy locally? Sounds like a deployment issue

Comment: yeah locally, I even tried uninstalling and reinstalling (as I suspected a corrupted file)

Comment: I've aslso checked the about:crashes in firefox, no mention of crashes there - the windows event viewer does have the records of the crashes though, but no real additional information.

Answer (score 0):

I have also observed that antivirus causes the Firefox to hang during the launch. Try disabling the antivirus and rerun your script to verify that in your case also the antivirus/firewall is causing the issue.

Comment: That is my next thing to try.

Comment: Have tried pausing antivirus and the machine has no firewall - there was no change in behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Check the version of Firefox on both computers. I have two Windows machines with Selenium 2.45.0. One machine has Firefox 37.0.2 and the code below executes fine. The other machine I just updated to Firefox 38.0.1 and I receive that error message box.

```
@Test
public void testFirefoxDriver() throws Throwable
    {
    new FirefoxDriver();
    }
```

I've been using Selenium for over a year now. Our production server automatically updates Firefox and this occasionally causes incompatibilities between Firefox and Selenium. I would expect to see a new Selenium release very soon.

Comment: I did think the same thing - I went to the laptop (the machine which works) and when I checked the version, firefox (helpfully) updated itself to 38.0.1 (which is the same as the version on the machine which fails) - i thought I had made a major messup - however, the laptop still works fine and the other machine doesn't.

Comment: I did try your code and it has the same issue as mine - which I am glad and sad about in equal measures :)

Comment: @M G - I tried downgrading the version of Firefox to 37.0.2 and it launched with no issues. Upgraded and it failed.  Still doesn't explain why the laptop is working - but does look more like maybe a new version of selenium is needed?

Comment: Selenium 2.46.0 is out as of 04-June...finally. My code stub above now runs successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox 38.x is not supported by Selenium 2.45.1. Either you have to roll back your firefox to 37.x or wait until next revision of Selenium.

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/437

Comment: It's interesting - one of my machines works perfectly with it - guess this is a lucky machine :)

Answer (score -1):

I've got this same issue. Funnily enough it was working yesterday morning I started getting it yesterday afternoon and now it appears to be messing up my tests.

I have Selenium 2.45.0 & Firefox 38.0.1.

My tests were running perfectly before this started happening and nothing has changed in my code. I've also ran another test suite just to make sure that it wasn't the one I was working on. The same thing happened.

I've just uninstalled firefox downloaded the previous version and they now work again with no crash.